# Unable to Build Spring App through Maven plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-boot, maven-plugin

I am trying to build a simple SpringBoot App in my Local PC in Eclipse using Maven. But this fails in Eclipse, **whereas running fine if executed through Command Prompt**. Require your help.

**The error shown in Eclipse are**

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org  pom.xml /springboottest line 1  Maven Configuration Problem
CoreException: Could not get the value for parameter compilerId for plugin execution default-compile: PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:1.0, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.5.5, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.2.2: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect timed out pom.xml /springboottest line 21 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
CoreException: Could not get the value for parameter compilerId for plugin execution default-testCompile: PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:1.0, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.5.5, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.2.2: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect timed out pom.xml /springboottest line 21 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6, classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources:default-resources:process-resources)

org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6, classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1362)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1360)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6, classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolveInternal(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:218)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.EclipsePluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(EclipsePluginDependenciesResolver.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.createPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:422)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:385)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getPluginRealm(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:231)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:102)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6, classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:367)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolveInternal(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:210)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    ... 40 more
    pom.xml /springboottest line 21 Maven Build Problem
Execution default-testResources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6, classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources:default-testResources:process-test-resources)

org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-testResources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6, classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1362)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1360)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6, classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolveInternal(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:218)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.EclipsePluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(EclipsePluginDependenciesResolver.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.createPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:422)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:385)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getPluginRealm(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:231)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:102)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6, classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:367)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolveInternal(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:210)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    ... 40 more
    pom.xml /springboottest line 21 Maven Build Problem
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)    pom.xml /springboottest line 21 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)   pom.xml /springboottest line 21 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

**Below is my Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.arun</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>



    <name>springboottest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>

    </parent>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-gradle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**This is my Maven Preference settings in Eclipse. I have referred to my local Maven path**

[image: Maven Settings in my Eclipse]

Comment: That's a very out of date version of Maven, what happens if you use the embedded version?

Comment: I face same issue even if i use embedded version

Comment: Maybe you have some invalid proxy setting in Eclipse? Try running with -X flag (verbose) and see if there any pointers in the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **mirrors** worked for me . If you are using internet with **firewalls and proxies**  this issue might happen

Here is the Maven Mirror documentation [Maven Mirror docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
......
 <mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>uk.maven.org</id>
        <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
        <name>UK Central</name>
       <url>http://uk.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </mirror>    
 </mirrors>
.....
</settings>
```